# GetPage binding not working with Navigator - GetX

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation, flutter-state

GetView is unable to find the controller i registered using Bindings in Navigator. i navigate to the GetView with Get.toNamed() and pass the route name and the Navigator ID;

Hey, i have the following setup (for illustration):

The controller:

```
class DetailsPageController extends GetxController {...}
```

The binding:

```
class DetailsPageBindings extends Bindings {
    @override
    void dependencies() {
        Get.put(DetailsPageController());
    }
}
```

The method Navigator.onGenerateRoute returns the following GetPage for route /detailsPage:

```
GetPage(
  name: "/detailsPage",
  page: () => const DetailsPage(),
  binding: DetailsPageBindings(),
)
```

The page itselft:

```
class DetailsPage extends GetView<DetailsPageController>() {...}
```

when i try to navigate to the page with `Get.toNamed("/detailsPage", id:..., )`, i get the following:

```
DetailsPageController() not found, you need to call Get.put() or Get.lazyPut()...
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace your **Get.put();** to **Get.lazyPut();** in Bindings.

Example :

```
class DetailsPageBindings extends Bindings {
    @override
    void dependencies() {
        //Get.put(DetailsPageController()); remove this
        Get.lazyPut<DetailsPageController>(() => DetailsPageController());// add this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ! but using lazyPut() didnt help either.

Comment: One thing i noticed, is when i EXPLICITLY call DetailsPageBindings.dependencies() in GetPage.page callback before returning the DetailsPage() it works. But that is not what i want and the controller is not deleted automatically when i remove the page from the navigation stack.